# htaccess mod_rewrite allow ipv6

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, syntax, ipv6

I want to allow two different IP, one version 4 and second version 6. For ipv4 it works fine but I don't know what is correct syntax to allow ipv6. Example of ipv6 is `2001:718:1001:500:300:7ede:9ac1:8a68`

Here is what I have:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^213\.168\.132\.69 # works
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^2001\:718\:1001\:500\:300\:7ede\:9ac1\:8a68 # doesn't works
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.html$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif) [NC]
RewriteRule .* /maintenance.html [R=302,L]
```

Comment: You don't need to escape `:` characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `RewriteCond` line has to match the address in exactly the way that mod_rewrite expects is. The `:` doesn't need to be escaped. To get it right you can turn on mod_rewrite logging with something like:

```
LogLevel rewrite:trace1
```

After that you'll see the client's IP address in the log files. Mine showed up as:

```
... mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 2a00:8640:1:0:c0b7:d175:5b0d:66f:51460] ...
```

The last bit is the port number, so leave that off. I used `2a00:8640:1:0:c0b7:d175:5b0d:66f` in my mod_rewrite rules and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to match ipv6 address your Apache needs to be listening on ip6 address using something like this:

```
Listen [2001:db8::a00:20ff:fea7:ccea]:80
```

**[Read more about binding IP address in Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/bind.html)**

Comment: Hi. Sort of late to the party, but where do you put this? In /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf? Thx.

Comment: Yes, this is needed to be in your main apache config file.